# 14.04 Keyboard Ctrl-L, Super-L, Alt-L register as Shift L for some reason

Tags: 14.04, keyboard

I seem to be having this strange keyboard problem where when I press either buttons <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, they all individually register as <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>. My keyboard layout is English (US). I'm using [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00LSGKEC4) keyboard, if it helps.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your keyboard likely uses the Microdia chipset `0x0c45:0x7603`. You can check by running `lsusb -v` and look for your keyboard in the output.

I wrote a driver for a keyboard with that chipset: https://bitbucket.org/Swoogan/aziokbd/overview

I also [blogged about it](http://swoogan.blogspot.ca/2014/09/azio-l70-keyboard-linux-driver.html).